# Adding thumbnails to basic jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I have used the Basic jQuery slider which can be found at http://www.basic-slider.com/ and it works in my site. I am pretty new to jQuery but understand HTML and CSS pretty well. I was just wondering, is there a way to make it so rather than the numbers underneath the images, it comes up with thumbnails of the images above it?

My code is pretty much exactly the same as the code given but altered to my own website.

I'm bad at explaining things but I hope I've explained myself properly at hope somebody can help!

Thanks

Comment: may be we could help better if you add your code to your question

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an image tag and add the images between each anchor tag where the site you linked has 1,2,3.